# How to grab select value with jQuery and pass to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of a select input when a button is clicked but can't for the life of me get it to work (long week).

**HTML**

```
        <tr>
            <td>
              <%= select_tag :thermal, options_for_select(AdminPrinter.all.map{|ap| [ap.name, ap.ip_address]}) %><br /><br />
              <input id = "thermal-button" type='button' value='Print Thermal Receipt'  />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**jQuery** - so far....

```
$("input#thermal-button").on("click", function(){
  var p = $(this).closest('select');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.closest()` selects the closest **parent**. Since select is just a sibling and not the parent of the input you cannot reach it like that.

In this case if the select is right before the input you can use `.prev()` which selects the previous element.

```
var selval = $(this).prev('select').val();
```

If it is not you can either select it by an ID or go to the parent and search for the select

```
var selval = $(this).closest('td').find('select').val();
```

or to filter the `<br>` use

```
var p = $(this).prevAll('select').val();
```

```js
$("input#thermal-button").on("click", function() {
  var p = $(this).prevAll('select').val();
  alert(p);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>okay</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <input id="thermal-button" type='button' value='Print Thermal Receipt' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @James could you maybe show the generated HTML markup? I updated my answer since I saw the `<br>`. Does it work now with `.prevAll`?

Comment: how do i then pass that value to another function, say one that looks like this: `function onLoadImage( ) { code here};`

Comment: You call the function `onLoadImage(p)` or if you want you can do something like `.click(onLoadImage)` and then use the code above to get the value. There are more ways of doing this depending on what you're doing inside that function